# Printf and fprintf prints only first argument

Tags: c, null, printf

I have a problem I can't grasp with printf. It's the first time ever I have this problem, so I'm sure it's something naive, but no matter what, I can't solve it myself... maybe it's just because I'm tired: fprintf (and i've found it's true also for printf) correctly prints only the first argument, from the second it will print only "0" for numbers and "(null)" for strings

Here's the relevant code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void printInputStream(MatePair* inputStream, char* leftFile, char* rightFile){

    MatePair* iterator = inputStream;
    FILE* outLeft = fopen(leftFile, "w");
    FILE* outRight = fopen(rightFile, "w");


    while (iterator->leftRow != MATEPAIR_STOP){

        fprintf(outLeft, "%d: \n", iterator->leftRow);
        fprintf(outLeft, "%s \n", iterator->leftDNA);
        fprintf(outLeft, "%d: %s \n", iterator->leftRow, iterator->leftDNA);

        iterator++;
    }

    fclose(outLeft);
    fclose(outRight);

}
```

Here's the beginning of the output:

```
48: 
NAATAGACCTATATCCTGTACCCAAACAGAAGACAGAGGATTAACCAAACTCTT 
48: (null) 
44: 
NTAGCCATCTTAGACACATGAATATCTTGGGTCACAACTCATACCTCAACAAAA 
44: (null) 
40: 
NAAAATAAGGGGTATACTCGCTTCGGGGCCCCATTTGGCCTCCAAAAGGGGGCG 
40: (null) 
36: 
NTCTATCTTGCTCGAGAGAAAGGGTTGCCTTAGGGTTTTTTGGGGGGGGCTGTA 
36: (null) 
32: 
NCTATAGAAATTTCCCATACCAACTAGACATTTATCTTCCTGTTTTTTTCCGCC 
32: (null)
```

As you can see I print every member of the array twice: once per argument and both arguments together. The data is fine, in fact with the first method it's all ok, with the second one only the first argument is printed.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: When compiling turn on all warnings (-Wall for gcc) and see if you get any warnings for the `fprintf`s. It is likely that `iterator->leftRow` is not an `int` but something of different type.

Comment: If you wrote a test case that passed an `int` and a `char *` to `fprintf()` you would find it works perfectly. This points to your data being the problem. @pmg is most likely correct in his answer below - your types are wrong, but I wanted to explain the line of thinking you should be using when approaching a problem like this.

Comment: For future reader the correct printf format for int64_t is %I64d.. or at least it works for me. Thanks everybody, as I suspected it was a very naive mistake. The problem is that usually I get warnings from the compiler for errors such as these, but it seems that this case is a bit different. Better start using -Wall -Wextra and -pedantic from now on :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does the following line, with a cast, "work"?

```
fprintf(outLeft, "%d: %s \n", (int)iterator->leftRow, iterator->leftDNA);
```

I suspect `iterator->leftRow` is **not** of `int` type (or some smaller type that gets converted to `int` automagically). If I'm right you invoke [Undefined Behaviour](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior); in the 1st case (the separate statements) there's no apparent "misbehaviour" (bad luck), in the 2nd case the "misbehaviour" is to print "(NULL)".

Comment: Yes, it's true! What a fool... leftRow is a int64_t (if I'm right the size of long long int is compiler dependant, I wanted to force it to be 64 bits long). So what's the correct format type in printf? I found it only for long and long long but I'm not sure it's ok

Comment: Ok, I've found it out. I mistook %I64d (uppercase i, correct) for %l64d (lowercase L, wrong), that's why i couldn't find it. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: The C99 Standard printf specifier for a value of type `int64_t` is `PRId64` (remember to `#include <inttypes.h>`), as in: `printf("%" PRId64 ": %s\n", v64, "string");`. I believe Microsoft's compiler is not C99 conformant so you have to use it's own unportable way (the `"%I64d"`) or cast to `long` and use `"%ld"` and hope the future doesn't break anything.

Answer (score 2):

Which data type has iterator->leftRow? Have you tried to do (i.e. assume it to be a long).

```
fprintf(outLeft, "%ld: %s \n", iterator->leftRow, iterator->leftDNA);
```